# Cumulatively sum a portion of a previous value with its next value

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I would like to create a column that sums the adjacent value and 80% of the previous value from another column. So, if column **x** is 1, 2, 3...10, I want column **z** to be 1, 2.8, 5.24, 8.192, etc.

Yet, here is my failed attempt:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c("")

df <- data.frame(x,y)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(y = cumsum(x*0.8))

Result: 

    x    y
1   1  0.8
2   2  2.4
3   3  4.8
4   4  8.0
5   5 12.0
6   6 16.8
7   7 22.4
8   8 28.8
9   9 36.0
10 10 44.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `for` loop to do this. It's important to initialize a vector first, especially if you're working with a large data set.

```
# initialize
newx <- vector("numeric", length(df$x))
newx[1] <- df$x[1]

for(i in 2:length(df$x)){
  newx[i] <- df$x[i] + (0.8 * newx[i-1])
}

newx
# [1]  1.00000  2.80000  5.24000  8.19200 11.55360 15.24288 19.19430 23.35544 27.68435 32.14748
```

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of `purrr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(y = accumulate(x, ~ .x * 0.8 + .y))

    x        y
1   1  1.00000
2   2  2.80000
3   3  5.24000
4   4  8.19200
5   5 11.55360
6   6 15.24288
7   7 19.19430
8   8 23.35544
9   9 27.68435
10 10 32.14748
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Reduce` function:

```
Reduce(function(last, current) current + last * .8, x = x, accumulate = T)

# [1]  1.00000  2.80000  5.24000  8.19200 11.55360 15.24288 19.19430 23.35544 27.68435 32.14748
```